# How to set RadFixedPage's Content to a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I want to set my RadFixedPage's content to a grid if it is possible.

At which point I will create a PDF file on users desktop. The grid is created in c# as you can see below. I have tried a couple times and could not seem to figure it out. I also tried to look through the documentation but could find no such example.

```
      using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test.pdf"))
      {
        RadFixedDocument document = new RadFixedDocument();
        RadFixedPage page = new RadFixedPage();
        Grid grid = new Grid();

        ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol3);

        RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition gridRow2 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition gridRow3 = new RowDefinition();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow2);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow3);

        TextBox text = new TextBox();
        text.Text = "This is text 0";

        TextBox text1 = new TextBox();
        text.Text = "This is text 1";

        Grid.SetRow(text, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(text, 0);

        Grid.SetRow(text1, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(text1, 1);

        document.Pages.Add(page);
        provider.Export(document, output);
      }
```